# Code is not working getting error

Tags: php, html, image

Getting error message :

> cannot be displayed because it contains some error.

```
<?php 
include("connection.php"); 
$height = 200; 
$width = 200; 
$border = 30; 
if($_GET['height']) {$height = $_GET['height'];} 
if($_GET['width']) {$width = $_GET['width'];} 
if($_GET['border']) {$border = $_GET['border'];} 
Header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
$image = ImageCreate($width+$border, $height+$border); 
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0); 
$blueish = ImageColorAllocate($image, 120, 120, 255); 
$redish = ImageColorAllocate($image, 222, 66, 66); 
$grayish = ImageColorAllocate($image, 200, 200, 200); 
$purpleish = ImageColorAllocate($image, 200, 10, 200); 
ImageFill($image, 0,0, $black); 
ImageFilledRectangle ($image, 0,0,$border,$height+$border, $grayish); 
ImageFilledRectangle ($image, 0,$height, $border+$height,$border+$width, $grayish);
$sql = "SELECT Battery FROM battery_level ORDER BY DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn ); 
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$den = $num*2+1; 
$xspacing = intval($width/$den); 
$pos = -1; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
   $pos = $pos +2; 
   $left = $pos*$xspacing; 
   $right = ($pos+1)*$xspacing;    
} 
ImageJpeg($image); 
ImageDestroy($image); 
?>
```

Comment: See source code in browser and you will see what are errors for this 'image'

Comment: Do you really think this is readable?

Comment: What is logged in the errorfile of PHP?

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`ImageJpeg($image, $path); //ex. $path = 'asset/image_name.jpg'`

you did not specify path of this file.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` is problem.